# Изменить регистр конкретной буквы текста в Python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь изменить регистр определенных букв в строке. Как это можно написать с помощью функции?

Пример: 'macdonald', пытаюсь изменить на 'MacDonald'.

Comment: Легко. С чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: def old_macdonald(name):
    return name[0].upper()+name[1:]+name[3].upper...первую букву перевел,но 4-ю пока не могу.

Comment: def old_macdonald(name):
    return name[0].upper()+name[:0]+'acDonald' практично ли такое решение ?

Comment: +name[:0]+'acDonald' по идее тут 2 раза одно и тоже. добавьте  побольше примеров. может проще руками написать переменная=КаКнАдО ?

Answer (score 5):

```
def change_case(s, positions=tuple()):
    return ''.join(c.upper() if n in positions else c for n, c in enumerate(s))


r = change_case('macdonald', (0, 3))
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, через промежуточное представление в виде списка:

```
text = 'macdonald'
characters = list(text)
characters[0] = characters[0].upper()                                       
characters[3] = characters[3].upper()                                       
new_text = ''.join(characters)
print(new_text)
```

Вывод:

```
MacDonald
```